# Taylor expansion validity

Tags: taylor-expansion

For example if I want to taylor expand $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ around $x = 0$ its quite hard to do it directly, could I just split it into $x(\frac{1}{1+x^2})$ and taylor expand the right expression which is much easier, if I'm only going to throw out higher order terms? If not, what is a simple counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: since, when $|x|<1$, you have$$\frac1{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots,$$then you have$$\frac x{1+x^2}=x-x^3+x^5-x^7+\cdots$$